# Change the position of grid after screen minimized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I wanna ask is it possible to change the grid position when the screen is minimized?

For example, the normal layout is like this

```
 _________    __________
|  First  |  |  Second  |
 ---------    ----------
```

And then when the screen minimized, it be like this

```
 __________ 
|  Second  |
 ----------    
 __________ 
|   First  | 
 ----------
```

I don't know if it can be done, but thanks for advance

Comment: You can use `flex box` and `order `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your talking about media queries. You should take a look at it here [MediaQueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            First
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            Second
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works with *Bootstrap 4*.

Another Example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXOZZV

Comment: I think the question is more about changing the order of the columns than stacking them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to achieve this.

```css
body {padding-top:5rem;}
.first, .second {
    padding:1rem;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="second col-md-6 col-md-push-6">Second</div>
        <div class="first col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">First</div>
    </div>
</div>
```